# VBA- Is it possible to code an If/Then statement based on if a trimmed text changes color from black to white

Tags: excel, vba

Current code below doesn't work because it finds the RsnChng is **always** = "Reason".

Initially where I thought the term "Reason" was popping up, I figured I could just code for that, but in actuality it's always there just not visible because it's colored black same as the background so you don't see it, - the text color for it turns white when it needs an action done.

So is there a way I could toss into the code below to determine the text color is white and then execute the code?

```
RsnChng = Trim(HE.CurrentHost.TextRC(20, 2, 6))
If RsnChng = "Reason" Then
    HE.CurrentHost.PutText "Finished by MPT055", 20, 20
    Utilities.PressKey "ENTER", False, UseIBM1, "6", , "YES", "BUTTONS"
End If
```

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: [CellFormat.Font property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.cellformat.font)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to get Font Color:

```
Function GetFontColor(Target As Range) As Integer
    GetFontColor = Target.Font.ColorIndex
End Function
```

Then use the same in IF condition.

```
If GetFontColor(Range("A1"))=2 then 
...
End If
```

And if you want to check Cell color then use the following

```
If Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
...
End If
```